# Julia: ctrl+c does not interrupt

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I'm using REPL inside VScode and trying to fix a code that gets stuck inside a certain package. I want to figure out which process is taking time by looking at the stack trace but cannot interrupt because REPL does not respond to ctrl+c. I pressed ctrl+x by accident and that showed ^X on the screen.

I am using JuMP and GLPK so it could be stuck there. However, I am not seeing any outputs.

I would also appreciate any tips on figuring out which process is causing it to be stuck.

Comment: What version of the Julia extension are you using? In general, hitting `^C` a bunch of times quickly should force throwing an interrupt.

Comment: Does any function call a function which is compiled code (of any other language)?  I know that, e.g., in MATLAB,  <CTRL>-C never reaches down to  MEX file content or operations.

Comment: @pfitzseb  Is that documented, or just random keyboard bashing on your part? I'm highly skeptical that anything in `julia`  responds to a stream of control characters.

Comment: I am using Julia1.4. I still haven't figured out what the problem is, but I got to get away with the code getting stuck by disbanding GLPK and using Gurobi.

Comment: @pfitzseb I hit ^C as fast as anyone can imagine but that didn't work

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Well, I did implement that feature recently (for the VSCode extension that is), but it's only in the very recent 1.1.15 release. The normal Julia REPL does something similar, see [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/5327824ec8c452410e2a2f755921764df9344855/src/signals-unix.c#L403) and [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/eb7618dbfa02147c060b37947c5d8becbb4e76a3/src/signal-handling.c#L47).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interrupts are not implemented in GLPK.jl. I've opened an issue: https://github.com/jump-dev/GLPK.jl/issues/171 (but it's unlikely to get fixed quickly).

If you're interested in contributing to JuMP, it's a good issue to get started with. You could look at the Gurobi.jl code for how we handle interrupts there as inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

I started out using **GLPK.jl** and I also found that it would "hang" on large problems. However, I recommend trying the **Cbc.jl** solver. It has a time limit parameter which will interrupt the solver in a set number of seconds. I found it to produce quality results. (Or you could use Cbc for Dev/QA testing to determine what might be causing the hanging and switch to GLPK for your production runs.)

You can set the time limit using the **seconds** parameter as follows.

For newer package versions:

```
model = Model(optimizer_with_attributes(Cbc.Optimizer
                                        ,"seconds" => 60
                                        ,"threads" => 4
                                        ,"loglevel" => 0
                                        ,"ratioGap" => 0.0001))
```

Or like this for older package versions:

```
model = Model(with_optimizer(Cbc.Optimizer
                             ,seconds=60
                             ,threads=4
                             ,loglevel=0
                             ,ratioGap=0.0001))
```